# What does "500 and 1" mean?

Tags: faa-regulations, weather, terminology

In this [AVWeb](http://www.avweb.com/news/airman/184279-1.html?redirected=1) article, numerous references are made to `500 and 1`, with other references to `3,000 and 5`.

Based on the statement `The current observation was 800 overcast and four miles visibility` (in the second paragraph), I would presume that `500 and 1` means a 500 foot ceiling and one mile visibility, is that correct?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your question -- you say "...was **800** overcast and **four** miles...", but then say "...a **500** foot ceiling and **one** mile..."

Comment: @Johnny, no typo: based on the second statement, I was assuming a meaning for the first statement. The question was for confirmation that my assumption was correct. I have edited to add some clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 500 and 1 is 500 ft ceiling and 1 mile visibility.

Comment: Thank you. It was your link to that article that prompted the question in the first place.